# Hibernate handle with tinyint column in mysql database?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

In my Hibernate Application have one field `Active` it is boolean type. 
My Hibernate Bean class column

```
    @Column(name = "ACTIVE")
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.YesNoType")
private boolean active;
//Setter and getter  methods
```

And in my service class writig code...

```
public void createUser(UserVO userVO) throws Exception {
    --------
    userVO.setActive(false);//setting false..
    ----
    ------//Database insert Code hear..
}
```

But i'm getting Exception hear..

```
    Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Incorrect integer value: 'N' for column 'ACTIVE' at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:2045)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1468)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect integer value: 'N' for column 'ACTIVE' at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2683)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2144)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2444)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1997)
    ... 53 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your problem here are two solutions,

1, if the type ACTIVE column is {tinyint}, you should use a short number in your code
eg.

```
userVO.setActive(Short.valueOf("0"));
```

2, if you have to use boolean type in your code, please `change the type of ACTIVE column to {char}`

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

From [hibernate types docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html):

> org.hibernate.type.YesNoType
>
> Maps a boolean to a JDBC CHAR type as ('N' | 'n') = false, ( 'Y' | 'y'
>   ) = true

So the table column type (tinyint) is not suitable to hold your value. Make it a char or varchar.